# Is the sentence "La pelota es roja. La niña juega con la" correct?

Tags: pronombres, objetos-directos

I've been thinking about this a lot:

> La pelota es roja. La niña juega con la.

As far as I can tell, the second sentence is correct, with "la" being the direct object pronoun. But the sentence ending with "con la" *sounds* wrong to my ears.

1. Is it correct?
2. Is there a better way to say "she plays with it"?

Comment: "la" is an object pronoun only before verbs (or occasionally after them as an "enclitic pronoun"): La patea (She kicks it). After a preposition, you need a pronoun like "eso" or "ella" to refer to the ball.

Comment: @Gustavson - Since comments aren't permanent, I'd suggest you add this to the answer, which is strong but not complete without what you explained.

Comment: "la" means "the" in femenine, it's a pronoun.The correct form  would be "it", which in femenine singular is "ella"."The girl plays with it" -> "La niña juega con ella". "The girl plays with the" -> "La niña juega con la".

Comment: @CptEric "la" is an article in "la pelota" (the ball) and a pronoun in "la patea" (...kicks it). In both cases, it expresses feminine gender, but grammatically speaking it's two completely different words.

Comment: you're correct @Gustavson in that they're separate meanings ( before a subject it's mean to be an article), but "la" must be followed by a verb in a time and form that makes sense, to be used as a pronoun ("la patea", "la alcanza"," la recoje", "la perdió".) <- the last one doesn't use the same verbal time as the start of the sentence, losing all sense and being incorrect.

Answer (score 14):

The correct sentence would be

> *La pelota es roja. La niña juega con ella.*

The pronoun *la* is the [clitic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clitic) non-emphatic object pronoun. Third-person object pronouns are not used after prepositions like this. It seems you might be calquing the English structure.

First- and second-person singular object pronouns *are* used after prepositions, as well as the reflexive pronoun *sí*:

- *conmigo* (*con + mí*), *contigo*, *consigo*
- *para mí, para ti, para sí*
- *sobre mí, sobre ti, sobre sí*

but in all the other cases you have to use the regular, emphatic pronouns:

- *con él, con ella, con ellos, con ellas, con nosotros, con vosotros/ustedes*
- *para él, para ella, para ellos, para ellas, para nosotros, para vosotros/ustedes*
- *sobre él, sobre ella, sobre ellos, sobre ellas, sobre nosotros, sobre vosotros/ustedes*

Answer (score 5):

In English, the word `la` means `the (feminine)`, so if you translate the phrase to English it would be like

> The ball is red. The girl plays with the.

When translating "`it`" to Spanish you have to remember if it's masculine or feminine and use `él` in first case or `ella` in second case.

Comment: I feel like trying to use direct translation between two languages which are so fundamentally different is always a mistake, even if in this case the translated sentence makes as much sense (aka none) as the original one.

Comment: That's correct, you can't transtale literally in most cases, but this sentence is really simple and I found out it actually _can_ (really _has to_) be translated that way.

Comment: It seems the OP was confusing it with the "la" in sentences like "la patea". But of course the point still stands.